# Aws cloud formation template: how to provide StreamName for Kinesis resource?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I wanted to create a Kinesis resource through cloud formation template and it wouldn't let me provide a "StreamName" as property for the resource.

```
"KinesisResource":{
"Type" : "AWS::Kinesis::Stream",
"Properties" : {
"ShardCount" : 1
"StreamName":"KinesisStream"
}

},
```

It says "unrecognizable property "StreamName".
how do I give a Stream Name in my template.
Thanks,
Nithya.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you can't specify a Stream name as of now. The Kinesis Documentation for the [CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html) supports only ShardCount as the only parameter.

You can perhaps get the Kinesis stream name as part of the CloudFormation Output - using

`{ "Ref" : "< resource name of instance of  - AWS::Kinesis::Stream>" }`

As of now the name of stream is created in the pattern of `<Stack-Name> - <Stream Name - Resoruce Name> - < Arbitrary Info >`

**Stack Name : MyKinesisStack**

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Resources" : {
    "KinesisStream1" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Kinesis::Stream",
      "Properties" : {
        "ShardCount" : "1"        
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs" : {
  "KinesisStreamName" : {
        "Description" : "Kenisis Stream Name",
        "Value" : { "Ref" : "KinesisStream1"}
    }  
  }
}
```

The above stack would create a Kinesis Stream with the name - **MyKinesisStack-KinesisStream1-ARTSDY32AS**

Comment: Hi Naveen, Thanks for your reply. Yes, this is what I did and used the output value in the OptionSetting of the Environment. But I still wonder because, the API has setStreamName, only the cloudFormation doesn't allow the naming of a stream.

Comment: @NaveenVijay please update here when there is an official update on this.

Comment: Sure will do @advncd

Answer (score 2):

This has been solved with Name in Property.

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::Kinesis::Stream",
   "Properties" : {
      "Name" : String,
      "ShardCount" : Integer,
      "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ]
   }
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html